# Django URL error: noreversematch in my app

Tags: django

I'm seeing this error in my Django app

```
NoReverseMatch at /kaitorihyou/delete_fields_group/18

Reverse for 'delete_fields_group' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['kaitorihyou/delete_fields_group/(?P<fields_group_id>[0-9]+)\\Z']
```

This is the line in my template that is redirecting to this URL

```
<form action="{% url 'kaitorihyou:delete_fields_group' fields_group_id %}" method="delete">
```

My `urls.py` does contain this pattern in questiion

```py
app_name = "kaitorihyou"
urlpatterns = [
    path('delete_fields_group/<int:fields_group_id>', views.delete_fields_group, name="delete_fields_group"),
    # etc.
]
```

Why is the url pattern not matching?

If I change the `action=` in my form to this it works

```
<form action="/kaitorihyou/delete_fields_group/{{ fields_group_id }}" method="delete">
```

Comment: There is no `fields_group_id` parameter in the context. The fact that the `{{ fields_group_id }}` works is simply because it renders the empty string... So it does *not* work.

Comment: @hendrikschneider: no, it is `''`: the tuple is because it is a tuple of *all* parameters, but there is only one. This usually means that the parameter is *not* in the context.

Comment: I did not explicitly mention in the post, but the context fields_group_id is provided as an argument to the render method in my view. this is why the other option not using the url tag works

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

The problem was that urls.py didn't contain a trailing slash, so

```
# this is wrong
path('delete_fields_group/<int:fields_group_id>', ...),

# should be this
path('delete_fields_group/<int:fields_group_id>/', ...),
```